0.0 is getting converted to 0 in reactive forms
Using formcontrol we have a field with type=number (can't remove it)
<input #num type="number" formControlName="number" />

If user enter's 0.0, reactive form is reading it as '0'. I want to read it as 0.0 and apply validations to it.
Sample stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56862279-gtv2kg?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html%3AL19,pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Angular uses parseFloat() to parse type=number inputs. You'll have to switch to a text based input.

I need type=number to have the stepper functionality so can't remove it

You can't have it both ways. If the decimal has no value it will be stripped.

"I want to read it as 0.0 and apply validations to it." What validations on a number do you need that involve the text in the input box? Why "0.0" and not "000000.00000"?

You can use type="text", then use a directive to restrict only numbers and dots. To make the input more user friendly you can consider ngx-mask to create an overlay that will help the user, what kind of input is expected.
TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[numbers-only]',
})
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  keyDownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event.which);
    if (
      event.which !== 190 &&
      event.key.length === 1 &&
      (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)
    ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  numRegex = /^\d+\.\d+$/;

  constructor() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      number: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(this.numRegex),
      ]),
    });
  }
}

HTML:
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ion-col>
      <input #num numbers-only type="text" formControlName="number" />
      <span
        style="color: red"
        *ngIf="(
          myForm.get('number').hasError('pattern') &&
          myForm.get('number').touched)"
        >Invalid input.</span
      >
    </ion-col>
    <br />
    <br />

    {{ myForm.get('number').errors | json }}
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    {{ myForm.get('number').value | number }}
  </form>
</ion-content>

Stackblitz Demo
